# How do I copy a file to the clipboard in the terminal and paste it with the gui (linux)

Tags: linux, terminal, copy-paste, clipboard, gui

I would like to copy a file to the clipboard with the terminal, like when right clicking a file and selecting "copy" in the gui. Someting like "cp test.txt" (without a destination) so whenever I want, I could right click and paste the file (or files) in the gui. So I will use a command to copy a file, not only the contents, and use "Ctrl v" or the mouse to paste it in UI

[A demo of what I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73Ii8.png) {

1. No file in clipboard
2. What I am trying to do: (copy a file to the clipboard with the terminal). Exactly like right clicking a file and selecting copy. (test.txt already on desktop)
3. Now the file is in the clipboard and I can paste it anywhere with "Ctrl v" or with the mouse
4. File is pasted

}

[This is exactly what I want to do only I need it in Linux instead of Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjMlB.png)